# How do I replace all uppercase letters with a dash and lowercase with regex?

Tags: php, regex

How does one replace all uppercase letters with a dash and lowercase equivalent in php?

Such as `understandRegexBetter` to `understand-regex-better`?

My Google-fu and experimentation with the following code hasn't gotten me very far.

```
echo preg_replace('/[A-Z]+/', "-$'", "understandRegexBetter");
```

Edit:
I forgot to specifically state that the first character is never uppercase.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do a replace twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
echo  strtolower(preg_replace('/([A-Z]+)/', "-$1", "understandRegexBetter"));
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, this will fail on `TestString` (`-test-string`). Doesn't seem like OP specifically requested that, though.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this:

```
echo strtolower(preg_replace('~(?=[A-Z])(?!\A)~', '-', $str));
```

Comment: I really like this solution, didn't know about `\A`.

Comment: @Sam: `\A` is the anchor for the start of the string, but stay unchanged when you use the multiline mode unlike `^`.

Comment: @HamZa: I was loosing myself in a strange way too before writing this answer.

Comment: Yea, Google let me know that.  Good to know how it works with the `m` modifier, I could see myself banging my head over that in the future.

Answer (score 8):

**Preferred Method:**

This method replaces any set of capital letters preceded by a lowercase letter with a `-` and the set of capital letters.  Then we lowercase the whole string after the fact.

```
echo strtolower(preg_replace(
    '/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z]+)/',
    '-$1',
    'understandRegexBetter'
));
```

---

**RegEx Callback:**

Uses [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to replace any set of capital letters with a `-` followed by the letters passed through `strtolower()`.  This, however, will leave a preceding `-` in your string (we could look for a preceding characters in the RegEx, but then your first letter would be left uppercase).

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/[A-Z]+/',
    function ($matches) {
        $character = reset($matches);
        return '-' . strtolower($character);
    },
    'understandRegexBetter'
);
```

---

**Deprecated:**

Side note, you can technically use `preg_replace()` with the [`e` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) but it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.  An example would be:

```
echo preg_replace(
    '/([A-Z]+)/e',
    '"-" . strtolower("$1")',
    'understandRegexBetter'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$s = 'understandRegexBetter';
$r = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])~',
    function ($m) { return '-' . strtolower($m[1]); }, $s);
echo $r;
```

Comment: Yes I know, going to delete it. Other answers are better :)

Comment: Don't, your answer is the only that takes into accout `ThisCase`

Comment: Yes, actually I just realized that other answers aren't checking camel case.

Comment: OP didn't really ask for this, he asked to literally replace capital letters with `-` and `strtolower(letters)`.

Comment: @Sam: even if OP didn't ask that - we can assume. It's a generic task, so we all know it's required.

Comment: @Sam: Also look at OP's input string which is a camel case string.

Comment: Fair enough @zerkms, I added another section to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (e flag means evaluate):

```
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z])/e', "strtolower('-\\1')", "understandRegexBetter");
```

Comment: 'e' is deprecated and removed from new php version.

Comment: **-1** for using the deprecated `e` modifier, use `preg_replace_callback()` instead

Comment: Good point, shame on me for not keeping up with specs. I just wrote this from top of my head, have not used it in a long time, just remembered. Thanks for the advice.