# How to change camelCase to slug-case (or kabob-case) via regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

For some reason, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849950/how-do-i-replace-all-uppercase-letters-with-a-dash-and-lowercase-with-regex) I found for (supposedly) how to do it in php just gives me the wrong matches. 
It seems to add the dash, but also replace the capital letter with a copy of the remainder of the string, so I want "abcZxc" to turn into "abc-zxc", but instead it turns it into "abd-zxczxc"

This, plus a bunch of other variations, is what I've tried, but can't get it to work.

```
filterGroup = aNiceString;
console.log(filterGroup.replace(/[A-Z]+/g, "-1$'"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's the problem? The regex works just the same way, and `toLowerCase()` shouldn't be too difficult either.

Comment: Can you include your code and example input/output in your question?

Comment: Next time, either do your homework, or bring the community an example of what you've tried (a jsFiddle, for example) or what specifically bugs you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var result = "fooBarBaz".replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase(); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: for me,the abcDef is coming as abc-$1ef. I want the output as abc-def.What should I do? @Henrik

Comment: This solution returns "-foo-bar" for "FooBar". Does anyone have a compact alternative to suppress a replacement for the first character?

Comment: You can use `"FooBarBaz".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1-$2").toLowerCase()` to avoid the leading dash

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = yourString.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "-$&").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: console.log("yourString".replace(/[A-Z]/g, "$0-").toLowerCase()) just prints: your$0-tring, so this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to use `$&` instead of `$0` in JavaScript to access the entire match.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant which splits into an array which is joined again right away, this avoids the leading `-`:

```js
let result = "FooBarBaz.".match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g).join('-').toLowerCase();
console.log(result);
```