# regex expression needed javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to achieve the following using regex in javascript:

```
convert --> "thisIsTheFunniestStuff"

to --> "this-Is-The-Funniest-Stuff"
```

I used the following regex:

```
/\B[A-Z]/g
```

My understanding was that I needed to target the position just before an uppercase letter to insert a hypen at that location

I also tried - `/[a-z]\B[A-Z]/`

**PS. I also don't understand when people write $1 $2 at the end after finishing the expression. $ is for end of input but why not include it in the expression itself.**

Comment: Why `I` of `is` is in lowercase but `T` of `The` is not changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758284/how-to-find-an-uppercase-letter-in-a-string-and-replace-it-with-a-dash-followed

Comment: thanks rajesh. just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and within the replace string you can use matched string by using [Specifying a string as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) option.

```js
var str = "thisIsTheFunniestStuff";

console.log(
  str.replace(/\B[A-Z]/g, '-$&')
)

// with positive look-ahead assertion
console.log(
  str.replace(/(?=\B[A-Z])/g, '-')
)
```

Comment: Hi pranav, could you please explain why ('-$&') this was used instead of a simple hypen like so ("-").

Comment: @nishkaush :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: @nishkaush :  the would match  `I` and replacing it with `-` will remove the character `I` itself... instead we need to replace it with `-I` , that's what the `$&` is doing... which holds the matched string...